# transaction to delete table content and reload using insert statement and check if inserts executed then commit and print message else rollback

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to SQL and seeking help to write SQL transaction to delete table content and reload using insert statement and check if inserts are properly executed then commit and print message else rollback.

```
    Delete from tableName;

    BEGIN Transaction insert into Product(num, name, quan, color)      
    values(1,'Product A', '1','Red');

    if Transaction > 0 commit; else Rollback;
```

Comment: Post your tried code and show some examples.

Comment: i just posted below, pls help

Comment: tried with this  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT 0 --Statements To Excecute     
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  IF(@@TRANCOUNT>0)
  ROLLBACK
  END CATCH

Comment: Which database. You tagged it for mysql ans plsql. Which is the database you are using

Comment: I am using PL SQL. oracle 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `PLSQL` block:

```
begin
     begin
          delete from product;
          commit;
     end;

     begin
          insert into product
                      (num,
                       name,
                       quan,
                       color
                      )
               values (1,
                       'Product A',
                       '1',
                       'Red'
                      );

        commit;
     Exception              
          when others then --If any issue happens with insert transaction willbe rolled back.
           rollback;         
     end;
end;
```